# Set default values for sympy lambdify arguments

Tags: python, sympy

I know that sympy’s [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) function can create a lambda with arguments `variables` and body `expression` like this:

```
lambdify(variables, expression)
```

so

```
lambdify((Symbol('x'), Symbol('y')) , 'x**2 + y')
```

produces

```
lambda x, y: x**2 + y
```

But how do I give default values to some of the variables? To get something like

```
lambda x, y=0: x**2 + y
```

?

I know I can do this with strings like `lambdify(('x', 'y=0') , 'x**2 + y')`, but I need to work with sympy symbol objects, since I’m extracting them from other sympy expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it works with strings is an accident. The way lambdify works is it creates a string form of the expression, then evals the string `"lambda %s: (%s)" % (', '.join(map(str, args)), expr)` (it's actually a little more complicated than that in general, but that's the basic idea). So if args is `('x', 'y=0')`, that ends up being inserted as `lambda x, y=0: ...`.

Right now `lambdify` doesn't have an option to make the parameters keyword arguments, so your best options are:

- Create keyword arguments manually using strings (what you already discovered works), or
- Wrap the lambdified function in a new lambda, like

  ```
    lambda x, y=0: lambdify((x, y), expr)(x, y)
  ```

  To do it in the general case, you can write some function that creates a keyword argument wrapper with whatever logic you want, like

  ```
    from functools import wraps

    def create_wrapped(args, expr):
        func = lambdify(args, expr)
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*_args, **kwargs):
            # Write the logic here to parse _args and kwargs for the arguments as you want them
            return func(*actual_args)
        return wrapped
  ```

Comment: i think i will just convert to a string and use that

Comment: Also : import functools